# penalized his drug possession

Tags: definition

Is the following use of "penalize" natural?

> The court penalized his drug possession.

Could you find its definition in a non-leanrer's dictionary?

Comment: Have you looked?  eg cambridge dictionary "punish someone for breaking a rule".  Or are you asking about the details of the grammatical structure "penalise his crime"

Comment: The usage you quote has a peson as the object. The sentence I use has an offense as the object.

Comment: Did you see that sentence somewhere, or did you come up with it yourself as an example?

Comment: I made it up myself to see if it is correct.

Comment: It sounds wrong to my ears, but Google turns up more hits for "penalize the crime" than it does for "penalize the criminal." Some of those hits even seem to be part of actual legal codes. So I guess it's OK.

Comment: What concerns me is that, even though "penalize" can take an offense as object, the meaning might not be actually punishing, but rather declaring an offense punishable.

Comment: Courts do not penalize people for crimes, like drug possession. Courts sentence offenders or put them on probation, etc. This is how it might be used: The Sports' Authority penalized the athlete for drug possession by suspending him for two years.

Answer (score -1):

That is fairly normal usage, for a written report of some kind, but towards the more formal end of the spectrum.

More normal for informal usage would be "The court punished him for his drug possession."

Comment: Could you find its definition in the dictionary?